# How to run hand written Coded UI in different browsers

Tags: c#, automation

At our firm we are developing web based app and I am maintaining the hand written Coded UI project. The problem is that it runs Internet Explorer by default, but it always crashes with different problems. For example sometimes it can locate and modify a combobox value, or sometimes it cannot. 
Is there any chance to run these tests in Edge, or in Chrome? 
As I see in the project it's using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting for the browser launch, and it is a dll file which I cannot modify. 
I have already installed the Selenium Cross Browser extension, but as I mentioned I cannot modify the root part where the BrowserWindow.Current Browser is located to run the tests in different browser.
Is there any solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Literally pasted your question title in google and the first result is: [Use Different Web Browsers with Coded UI Tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-different-web-browsers-with-coded-ui-tests).

Comment: I am using VS Enterprise 2017 and I couldn't find any "User-unhandled" option in the Common Language Runtime Exceptions. 
As I mentioned above I have installed the Selenium for Cross Test Browsing but I can not change the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll file where the CurrentBrowser is located

Comment: Once again did 10 seconds search for you and: for User-unhandled Right click CLR exceptions and select `Continue when unhandled in user code`. For CurrentBrowser: [Troubles changing current browser in Coded UI Tests
](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21689187/754438)

Comment: sorry but I am new in this, and I couldn't solve the current browser issue.
so here is the login page code: 
 public class LoginView
    {
        public BrowserWindow Browser { get; }

        public LoginView(BrowserWindow browser)
        {
            Browser = browser;
        } 

I do not know where should I modify the code because it has plenty of references for "Browser"

Comment: I already gave you a link to super simple example. How hard is to copy/paste `BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "firefox";` and try if it works. If you can't even do suck a simple thing, I am really sorry but no one in SO can help you in this case. Ask you college to sit down next to you and do some pair-programming.

Comment: Yes I already pasted that, but unfortunately still IE starts, and then the Chrome goes into a loop by launching the browser again and again. (I chose Chrome instead of Firefox) . I did everything what you sent to me, so yes I am going to ask my colleague about this issue. Thank you for your help patience.

Answer (score 0):

I think setting the default browser in visual studio by pressing the drop down option next to the start button should fix your issue.

Comment: I cannot set that because there is no possibility to set a start up project, because there are only the page opjects entities and the ordertest files